# "No module named pygame" on a python to exe file

Tags: python, pygame, py2exe

I was testing pygame with auto_py_to_exe and it came up with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "drawrect.py", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'
```

Image:

[image]

Code:

```
import pygame

Rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 150, 150)
Rect.center = (240, 240)
white = (255, 255, 255)
surface = pygame.display.set_mode((480, 480))

pygame.init()

while True:
    surface.fill((0, 0, 0))
    pygame.draw.rect(surface, white, Rect)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: have you run `'python -m pip install pygame'`, or simply `'pip install pygame'` yet?

Comment: this worked, ty!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pip install pygame` is the command you are looking for.

Run this command in your terminal and then try again.